# error : 'return' expression required in a function with a block body

Tags: kotlin

This is the program i used to iterate through loop and it will do all the mathematical operation for the variable.

```kotlin
fun main(){
    val list1=listOf('+','-','*','/')
    val a:Double= 10.0
    val b:Double= 2.0
    for (i in list1){
        println({operation(a,b,i)})
    }
}

fun operation(a:Double,b:Double,i:Char): Double {
    when(i){
        '+'->return a+b
        '-'->return a-b
        '*'->return a*b
        '/'-> return if (b==0.0){ -1.0 } else{ a/b }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a value from `operation` function, currently if `i` is something else than
`'+'`, `'-'`, `'*'`, `'/'` you are not returning anything. if these are the only actions then you can update your code as

```
   fun operation(a:Double,b:Double,i:Char): Double {
        return when(i){
            '+'-> a+b
            '-'-> a-b
            '*'-> a*b
            else -> if (b==0.0) -1.0 else{ a/b }
        }
    }
```

you can make it even shorter with expression body as

```
   fun operation(a: Double, b: Double, i: Char) = when (i) {
        '+' -> a + b
        '-' -> a - b
        '*' -> a * b
        else -> if (b == 0.0) -1.0 else { a / b }
    }
```

Comment: As a matter of style, it's often better to treat ‘impossible’ cases explicitly, e.g. by throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`.  As written, if a bug causes your program to call `operation(3, 2, '^')`, it would return `1.5`, which could hide the bug; throwing an exception would make it much easier to spot and fix the bug.  (For the same reason, `Double.NaN` might be a better return value than `-1.0` if the denominator is zero.)

Comment: But here i is from the list1 only so it will never give the character which is out of the list, then why we need to mention else there

Comment: @MustafaDahodwala You would need to mention it because if someone passes that character '!' for `operation` it will also divide when it should probably throw an  error or return null instead. As the code is here it is also more likely that the developer will forget to add the new case (and be more difficult to debug) if a new operator is added later on.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your `when` statement. If `i` is not one of the given cases, your method will exit the `when` and return nothing.

The simplest solution is just to add a return at the end of the method, or add and else branch:

```kotlin
fun operation(a:Double,b:Double,i:Char): Double {
    return when(i) {
        '+'-> a + b
        '-'-> a - b
        '*'-> a * b
        '/'-> if (b == 0.0) { -1.0 } else { a / b }
        else -> -2.0 // this is just some arbitrary value you can check outside the loop
    }
}
```

or more simply

```kotlin
fun operation(a:Double,b:Double,i:Char): Double = when(i) {
    '+'-> a + b
    '-'-> a - b
    '*'-> a * b
    '/'-> if (b == 0.0) { -1.0 } else { a / b }
    else -> -2.0 // this is just some arbitrary value you can check outside the loop
}
```

You could simply make the last `'/'` case the else; however, you are likely to forget adding another case to the when if adding a new operator such as `'^'`. This example could be improved by returning a `Double?` from the method and return `null` in the  else branch which you can then check on the outside for an unrecognized operator.

Another route you could take, which would avoid adding the else case, is to add an operator enum. From the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression):

> If when is used as an expression, the else branch is mandatory, unless the compiler can prove that all possible cases are covered with branch conditions, for example, with enum class entries and sealed class subtypes).

Although this would likely be overkill for a simple program like this, you would also be ensureing that your program would ALWAYS warn you when you forgot to add a branch to the `when` if you decide to add new operators.